# If I provide this wall power strip 240V 50Hz instead of 120V 60Hz, what do I get back out?

Tags: adapter, outlet

I'm looking at [this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NLKVTQ4), and next to the plug, it says:

```
Input Voltage: AC110-250V
Maximum Power: 2500W 10A
USB Output: Total Max 3.4A
Frequency: 50/60Hz
```

It would seem to claim that I can use a tiny plug converter to plug it into a European (240V 50Hz) outlet instead of the usual American (120V 60Hz) outlet, and still get USB power back out.

...which is all well and good, but how do I tell what exactly would be the **AC output** in that case??

Like, the output would be an American plug, but would I get back 120V or 240V? 50Hz or 60Hz...? How do I tell?

Answer (score 3):

You will get out whatever AC voltage and frequency you put in.

However, since it has North American plugs and sockets, I would only use it in the US and Canada for our 120 V 60 Hz power.

Comment: I believe they use the same plug for 240V 50Hz in China. The product might be rated for use in both countries.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Regarding your last sentence, I mean, lots of devices can accept both 240V and 120V, so why shouldn't I use it with those devices in Europe?

Comment: AS I said, it has North American plugs and sockets, so I would expect it to be designed to safely handle our 120 VAC.  It would likely handle your 240 VAC, but it has the wrong plugs and sockets, so could not be easily used in Europe - and likely would not meet elelctrical code requirements there.

Answer (score 1):

In a wall power strip, the mains input wires connect directly from plug to sockets. You get out exactly what you put in, there is no electronics to change that.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, how do you tell if that's the case? It's a fairly chunky thing, so why wouldn't it have electronics to step down the voltage?

Comment: @user541686 Because that's how power strips work. At least the ones that cost $14.99. If the price were $1499 it could contain electronics to convert hundreds of watts of power from 240V to 120V but it would not fit the electronics into that size cube.

Comment: I'm confused... doesn't e.g. [this product](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07KXB5J35) claim to do exactly that?

Comment: @user541686 Yes it does. But you asked about power strips, not voltage-converting travel adapters that allow you to plug in low power 120V devices in a 240V country. Completely different pieces of equipment for different purpose with a different name, so different product.

Comment: Are you saying the need to simultaneously support pass-through 120V/60Hz->120V/60Hz would blow up the size and cost 100x? That seems to be the only difference between them.

Comment: @user541686 The power strip handles 2500W 10A because it's just direct copper wiring and what goes in must come out, no electronics or power conversion. The travel adapter is larger, and has electronics for universal input mains inverter which outputs only up to 240W 120V which is 2A. In marketing language. Might be pushing it. Generally you would have to pay more than that for a real product, but for a one-off or occasional use, it might not be overloaded too much.

Comment: I guess I could see that, but then what about [these things](https://www.amazon.com/2000Watts-Adapter-Converter-Voltage-Countries/dp/B07N1KWMQT/) claiming 2000W from a 2.4" x 2.2" x 2" cube? Are they falsely advertising?

Comment: @user541686 No not false advertizing, you did not read the fine print and you sort of have to know how it works. It is basically a dimmer that chops 240V to equal 120V on average. It may work on your dumb hair dryer but will fry any sensitive electronics such as 120V laptop chargers. Which it does warn about. Websites like that just want you to buy a product and give them your money even if there is not enough information to know what you are actually buying. They might not even know themselves what they are selling as long as someone buys it.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, I see. Thanks a lot!